# Flash - custom language instead of ActionScript

Tags: compiler-construction, flash

I recently heard of a language that gives the same functionality as ActionScript (creating flash SWF files) with a certain speed increase. The language was called something along the lines of 'hex'.

Does anyone have any idea what this language is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Haxe](http://haxe.org/)

> an open source toolkit based on a modern high level strictly typed programming language, a state-of-the-art light-speed cross-compiler, a complete cross-platform standard library, and ways to access to each platform's native capabilities. [Learn More...](http://haxe.org/#the-haxe-toolkit)

Comment: [This comment thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183603/can-we-get-some-consensus-on-what-flag-to-use-for-link-only-answers/183709#comment586303_183709) may have something to do with it :)

Comment: Relevant, but this question is from 2009 well before that discussion, and this is both the complete answer and a link to the site about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that you can use Haxe and AS3 together on a flash project, and while it would be better to use all Haxe it often make sense to use an existing library without converting it.  I have used as3 libraries in Haxe flash projects and when on a large Air project written in AS3 I swapped a font parser written in as3 with a much better Haxe one that could parse more fonts and was written in away that I could improve it even more, the app couuld now import fonts on a mac/pc that would only normally work on a pc/mac.  Using flashdevelop IDE to code Haxe and as3 it is very easy to mix and match.  But Haxe's main advantage is that code written in generic haxe can be moved between platforms, so it is much easier to move a flash banner created in haxe flash to haxe javascipt, some view details may need to be adjusted but the logic, tween engines etc... could be the same.  Then if I need to run a flash haxe game on Iphone I could use OpenFL ( c++ haxe ) with virtually no changes to my existing code.  Really Haxe is a game changer, and one of the best languages you can use.